# Numbers and letters validation in C

Tags: c, validation, digits, letter

I am new at programming and I faced up with validation. I try to write a program where the program gets the user’s `Name` and `Age` as inputs. And I need to check if the name contains only letters (it can have spaces) and if age is only from numbers.
I tried to use the functions `IsAlpha()` and `IsDigit()` but I think it’s not the right way in my program because it only checks the first character.
For example, if the user inputs “Jane123 or J0nas” an error appears and the same with numbers.

I think I should use something with while of if. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Include `ctype.h` and look at `isalpha()`, `isspace()` and `isdigit()`. The check 1 character at a time.

Comment: *I think I should use something with while*. Yes, you need to use a loop.

Comment: The notion of letters and digits is complex, since you should use [UTF-8 everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). What about characters like `é` or `Ê` (French letters) or my family name in Russian (Cyrillic letters) `СТАРЫНКЕВИЧ` ? You might consider using the [Glib library](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) or [GNU libunistring](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/) ... and is ❶ (U+2776 DINGBAT NEGATIVE CIRCLED DIGIT ONE) a digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you iterate over your input and check every single character or alternatively use `strspn`.

```
const char alpha[] = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const char digit[] = "0123456789";

if (strlen(Name) != strspn(Name, alpha)) {
    printf("Invalid Username\n");
    exit(-1);
}

if (strlen(Age) != strspn(Age, digit)) {
    printf("Invalid Age\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

But be aware, if you got your inputs from functions, like `fgets`, you probably have a containing newline character and it is required that you trim them first (remove all whitespace from the beginning and/or the end).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool checkName(char Name[]) {
    for (int i = 0; Name[i]; ++i) {
        if(!isalpha(Name[i])) {
            printf("Error!!!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char Name[] = "Jane123";
    checkName(Name);
}
```

if you want this function with `isdigit()` just copy paste and replace `isalpha()` with `isdigit()`